# Prove that $\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}=(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\overline{A_i})\cup(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty}A_{i+j})$.

Tags: general-topology

The following is an exercise from Engelking's General Topology.

Let $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of sets in a topological space. It is required to prove that $\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}=(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\overline{A_i})\cup(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty}A_{i+j})$. In my attempt I could show that $\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}\supseteq (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\overline{A_i})\cup(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty}A_{i+j})$ as follows.

For any $i\in \mathbb{N},$ $A_i\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$; so $\overline A_i\subseteq \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}$, whence $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \overline A_i \subseteq \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}$. For each $i\in\mathbb{N},\  \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. Hence $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty}A_{i+j}\subseteq \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}$ follows by a similar argument as above. So we have the aforementioned inclusion.

However, I failed to show the other inclusion. Could someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can show $B \subseteq C \cup D$ by proving $(B \setminus C) \subseteq D$. Hence suppose we have

$$x \in \Biggl(\overline{\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i}\Biggr) \setminus \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} \overline{A_i}.$$

We need to prove that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, we have

$$x \in \overline{\bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j}.$$

Fix $n$, and let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $x$. The closed set

$$F = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n-1} \overline{A_i}$$

doesn't contain $x$ by assumption, so $V = U\setminus F$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. By assumption, $V$ intersects $\bigcup A_i$, and by construction, $V$ doesn't intersect any $A_i$ with $i < n$, so

$$U\cap \bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j \supseteq V \cap \bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j \neq \varnothing$$

follows. Thus every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $\bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j$, i.e.

$$x \in \overline{\bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j}.$$

$n$ was arbitrary, hence

$$x\in \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \overline{\bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j},$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: Since $\bar C \cup  \bar D =\overline {C \cup D}$  we can say that for every $n \in \mathbb N$ we have  $x\in  \overline {C_n} \cup \overline {D_n}$  where $C_n= \cup_{j<n}A_j$   and $D_n= \cup_{j\geq n}A_j$,  but $x\not \in \overline  {C_n}$ so $x\in \overline  {D_n} .$...  So $x\in \cap_{n\in \mathbb N}\overline {D_n}. $